# nodejs: How to parse each column of a csv and based on each column value perform a desired task like:

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am having a master table in GCS, which is having information related to Bucket,source, big query dataset, big query table..based on a file landing in gcs it should be loaded into the bq with the mapped table.
like:
bucket    File    Dataset   Target
 A         A.csv    A         A.csv

A         B.csv    A         B.csv

B         A.csv    A         C.csv

How I can achieve this using nodejs function. 
here, is the code which I wrote:

parsing the csv:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
let readableStreamInput = fs.createReadStream('gs://…./Master_Table.csv');
let csvData = [];

fastcsv
  .fromStream(readableStreamInput, {headers: true})
  .on('data', (data) => {
  let rowData = {};

  Object.keys(data).forEach(current_key => {
     rowData[current_key] = data[current_key]
  });

  csvData.push(rowData);

}).on('end', () => {
  console.log('csvData', csvData);
  console.log('total rows of table', csvData.length);
})
```

Comment: You need to add more info to what do you want to do. the question in unclear and unlikely to be answered.

Comment: let me re-phrase it once, ultimate goal is to move the data dynamically to BQ as soon as the files comes in GCS.so, for this I am having a master table in GCS which is having four fields : Bucket Name, File Name, Dataset Name, Table Name..based on the mapping from the respective attributes I want the data to be inserted into BQ. I want to use nodejs for parsing the .csv file , and based on each column value it will ingest the data into BQ